# How to Stack Data Frames on top of one another (Pandas,Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say i Have 3 Pandas DF

DF1

```
 Words      Score
 The Man     2
 The Girl    4
```

Df2

```
 Words2      Score2
The Boy       6
The Mother    7
```

Df3

```
Words3       Score3
The Son        3
The Daughter   4
```

Right now, I have them concatenated together so that it becomes 6 columns in one DF.  That's all well and good but I was wondering, **is there a pandas function to stack them vertically into TWO columns and change the headers?**

So to make something like this?

```
Family Members     Score
The Man             2
The Girl            4
The Boy             6
The Mother          7
The Son             3
The Daughter        4
```

everything I'm reading here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html seems to only have "horizontal" methods of joining DF!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As long as you rename the columns so that they're the same in each dataframe, `pd.concat()` should work fine:

```
# I read in your data as df1, df2 and df3 using:
# df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
# Example dataframe:

Out[8]: 
      Words  Score
0   The Man      2
1  The Girl      4


all_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

# Give all df's common column names
for df in all_dfs:
    df.columns = ['Family_Members', 'Score']

pd.concat(all_dfs).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[16]: 
  Family_Members  Score
0        The Man      2
1       The Girl      4
2        The Boy      6
3     The Mother      7
4        The Son      3
5   The Daughter      4
```